# Child menus aren't showing up in InAppSettingsKit

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, inappsettingskit

I've implemented a view that is using an InAppSettingsKit controller, just like the example application shows, but for some reason, I can never access a child screen of any kind.

I have even tried adding a multi-select, but when I click on it from the application, it just shows the item as selected, but never takes me to the screen to select an option.

When I load the iOS settings application, everything works.

Could I be missing something simple and obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I actually got this to work.
For some reason, I needed to add Navigation controllers.  Not sure why this is?

Comment: The navigation Controller is how the views are changed. It is the code which makes thing navigable. So without the navigation controllers the tableView is trying to push the child view on to the screen but it can't because only the navigation controller knows how to do this.