# InAppSettingsKit child pane not showing, using Navigation controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, navigationcontroller, inappsettingskit, settings-bundle

I'm using InAppSettingsKit and my child panes are not showing up. I found a post ([Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447687/child-menus-arent-showing-up-in-inappsettingskit)) about using Navigation Controllers, which I am.
On the General.plist I have the same view as the Root.plist.  I have done some searching and all I can find is that you need to use Navigation Controllers. That is what I am using. Notice the "Done" button and the "\<\Settings" button.

Any ideas or thoughts thank you!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your Settings.plist work in Settings app? It looks like it doesn't find the child plist.

Comment: It looks the same in the settings app and the inappsettingskit tableviewcontroller. I have deleted the app from my device as well as the simulator, and then rebuild. Still no luck.

Comment: OK, so the problem is in your plists. Did you reference the `Filename` of the child plist in the root plist? When you do so, you should omit the ".plist" suffix.

Comment: That's it! Removing the .plist extension was the kicker. Working like a charm. Thank you so much Ortwin. iOS 6 uses the extension, I have not found any docs that instruct you to remove extension on iOS 7. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to correctly reference the `Filename` of the child plist in the root plist. When you do so, you should omit the ".plist" suffix.